# How to align two form input boxes with each other?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a modal with a form (using Bootstrap-Vue and Vue2). Each row has two fields. If user does not enter a valid value to the field, the state of the field returns `false`, making the box to be colored with red and add a message under the field. But I want both of the fields (in the same row) to be aligned with each other. The problem:

[image]

When I don't show an error, it looks good:

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="text-right">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="modal-label">שדה 1</div>
      <b-form-input
       :class="{ 'invalid-form-box': !stateField1(), 'modal-input': true}"
       v-model="course_number"
       type="number"
       placeholder="שדה 1"
       :trim="trimInput"/>
      <p v-if="!stateField1()" class="invalid-form-text">
        לא חוקי 1
      </p>
      <p v-if="!stateField2() && stateField1()" class="invalid-form-text"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="modal-label">שדה 2</div>
      <b-form-input
       :class="{ 'invalid-form-box': !stateField2(), 'modal-input': true}"
       v-model="score"
       type="number"
       placeholder="שדה 2"
       :trim="trimInput"/>
      <p v-if="!stateField2()" class="invalid-form-text">
        לא חוקי 2
      </p>
      <p v-if="!stateField1() && stateField2()" class="invalid-form-text"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
...
</div>

<style scoped>
  div {
    margin: auto 0;
    direction: rtl;
  }

  input {
    direction: rtl;
  }

  .modal-label {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }

  .modal-input {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }

  .modal-header .close {
    padding: 1rem 1rem !important;
    margin: -1rem auto -1rem -1rem !important;
  }
  
  .invalid-form-text {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #dc3545;
  }

  .invalid-form-box:focus {
    border-color: #dc3545;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(220 53 69 / 25%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .invalid-form-box {
    border-color: #dc3545;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>
```

How can I make them aligned? I tried to replace `<p>` with `<div>`, `<label>` and `<span>`. Also tried to use `<br>`.

Comment: And what HTML does that Vue render to the browser? Because that's what your CSS is going to work on.

Comment: Not sure how it happen but I was trying to make a boundary for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222877/how-to-resize-the-size-of-the-vuetifys-v-select/71231747#71231747 Please ignore this topic.

Answer (score 3):

The shifting is caused by the `margin: auto 0;` rule in:

```css
div {
  margin: auto 0; ❌ causes layout shift when error message appears
}
```

That rule sets the top and bottom margins of all `div`s to `auto`. Notice the vertical margins of the `div`s (`div.col-md-6` and `div.modal-label`) when there is no error:

[image: visualization of margins (without error)]

And when there is an error, the outer margins collapse to make room:

[image: visualization of margins (with error)]

#### Solution

I think you were only trying to set the horizontal margins to 0. You can do that with:

```css
div {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

[image: solution]

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/troubleshoot-bootstrap-vue-layout?file=src/components/MyForm.vue)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this. I recommend first one.

1. Make 'invalid-form-text' tag position absolute and fix it's position where you want and that will remove this layout shift.
2. If you are using flex use align-items: flex-start so when error appears alignment will align them to flex start and it will appear they are in same line. ( It should work but might not work due to other css conflicts- in case it didn't work just ask )

Answer (score 0):

If you use BootstrapVue, you can do something like:

```
<b-row align-v="start">
  <b-col cols="6">
    // Whatever goes in your first column
  </b-col>
  <b-col cols="6">
    // Whatever goes in your second column
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to parent div.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

This will put both inputs aligned next each other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line of code is responsible for showing or hiding error

```
<p v-if="!stateField2()" class="invalid-form-text">
```

You can have this p below each textbox

And your invalid-form-text class can be like this

```
.invalid-form-text{
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

The point here is that if you show hide elements with visibility style then element will still occupy space in DOM no matter they are visible or hidden, and it wont disturb alignments of elements

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make the **.invalid-form-text** element a height of 0px and make sure it's overflow is set to visible if not already.

If you need to add some margin to the element you could change your existing margin to transform: translateY which prevents it from affecting other elements in the dom layout.

```
.invalid-form-text{
   height: 0;
   overflow: visible;
   margin: 0px;
   transform: translateY(0.25rem);
}
```